# static "global" vector does not seem to be populated

Tags: c++, vector

Im somewhat new to C++, so Im making a simple game with SFML. I have a static vector defined in a header file that is then supposed to be populated with methods during runtime. The idea being that these methods will be ran each cycle automatically through the use of that vector. The vector looks like this in its Globals.h:

```
static std::vector<std::function<void()>> updateList;
```

which gets populated through a struct method in the Globals.cpp like this:

```
int Globals::AddToUpdateList(std::function<void()> update){
    updateList.push_back(update);
    return updateList.size();
}
```

which gets ran in say a bullet or player constructor like this to add the relevant method:

```
Globals globals;
updateIndex = globals.AddToUpdateList([this]() {Update(); });
```

This seems to work for as far as i can tell. I can confirm that this successfully populates the vector with a method (hopefully the one passed through).

However when I loop through the vector in the main.cpp its size appears to be 0 despite the vector being marked as static and me having confirmed something is pushed to it. Does anyone have an explanation and/or suggestions on how I can adress this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that static keyword for variable in h file means "local to compilation unit", so every cpp file which has this header file included has its own copy of this vector.

To make it work:

1. Move variable to any cpp file (probably globals.cpp)
2. In globals.h file declare this variable as extern

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks a ton!